# Анимация в unity и magicavoxel

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я создал анимацию в magicavoxel но она экспортируется в unity по одному кадру. Подскажите что мне делать?

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста поподробней проблему.

Comment: а шо говорят туторы с ютуба? их там много